# Starting Loop From Previous Number

Tags: loops, matrix, integer

Basically the error holds that I want the third loop to start increasing from what the second loops integer was. For example, Second loop is 0, third loop starts at 0, finished, second loop initializes and now is 1, third loop starts at 1, finished, second loop initializes and now is 2, third loop starts at 2, and so on.

If you don't understand that then I am lost for you but now for the code.

J is not increasing but integer is, i isn't or row isn't either. Thanks if you can solve.

public class Hello {

```
public static int integer = 0;

public static void fixThisMethod() {

    for(int row = 0; row < 10; row++)//Matrices Row
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            integer = i;

            for(int j = integer; j < 10; integer++)
            {
                System.out.println("Started From: " + integer + " Now On: " + j);
            }
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    fixThisMethod();
}
```

}

Comment: Looks awfully like a homework question..."J is not increasing but integer is". Why do you think that would be?

Comment: Wasn't HW but a short program I am developing. I actually would have thought but I guess not the case that j would be increasing because integer is setting j equal to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    public static int integer = 0;

public static void fixThisMethod() {

    for(int row = 0; row < 10; row++)//Matrices Row
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            integer = i;

            for(int j = integer; j < 10; integer++,j++)
            {
                System.out.println("Started From: " + integer + " Now On: " + j);
            }
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    fixThisMethod();
}
```

Your output

```
Started From: 8 Now On: 8
```

Started From: 9 Now On: 9
Started From: 1 Now On: 1
Started From: 2 Now On: 2
Started From: 3 Now On: 3
Started From: 4 Now On: 4
Started From: 5 Now On: 5
Started From: 6 Now On: 6
Started From: 7 Now On: 7
Started From: 8 Now On: 8
Started From: 9 Now On: 9
Started From: 2 Now On: 2
Started From: 3 Now On: 3
Started From: 4 Now On: 4
Started From: 5 Now On: 5
Started From: 6 Now On: 6
Started From: 7 Now On: 7
Started From: 8 Now On: 8
Started From: 9 Now On: 9
Started From: 3 Now On: 3
Started From: 4 Now On: 4
Started From: 5 Now On: 5
Started From: 6 Now On: 6
Started From: 7 Now On: 7
Started From: 8 Now On: 8
Started From: 9 Now On: 9
Started From: 4 Now On: 4
Started From: 5 Now On: 5
Started From: 6 Now On: 6
Started From: 7 Now On: 7
Started From: 8 Now On: 8
Started From: 9 Now On: 9
Started From: 5 Now On: 5
Started From: 6 Now On: 6
Started From: 7 Now On: 7
Started From: 8 Now On: 8
Started From: 9 Now On: 9
Started From: 6 Now On: 6
Started From: 7 Now On: 7
Started From: 8 Now On: 8
Started From: 9 Now On: 9
Started From: 7 Now On: 7
Started From: 8 Now On: 8
Started From: 9 Now On: 9
Started From: 8 Now On: 8
Started From: 9 Now On: 9
Started From: 9 Now On: 9
Error

```
java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
at java.lang.Object.notifyAll(Native Method)
```

Comment: I'll try this, looks from your results it did. I would think that j would keep getting set equal to integer but I guess it wasn't the case.

Comment: You don't need the variable 'integer' at all though. And it certainly doesn't make sense to have it increase at the same time as j.

Comment: Need it for other purposes later in the coding process, its going to follow j but also increase by 1 over j.